# Pandas not correctly plotting data but numpy is

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot the same data set using numpy and pandas and it is plotting correctly with numpy but not pandas - I am using the exact same code for both!

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# numpy version of dataset

X = iris.data[0:49, [0]]
Y = iris.data[0:49, [1]]

# turning numpy array into dataframes

sepal_width = pd.DataFrame(X)
sepal_length = pd.DataFrame(Y)

# plotting numpy array
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(X, Y)
ax.set_xlabel("Petal Length")
ax.set_ylabel("Sepal Length")
plt.show()

# plotting pandas df
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(sepal_length, sepal_width)
ax.set_xlabel("Petal Length pd")
ax.set_ylabel("Sepal Length pd")
plt.show()
```

Numpy plotted

[image]

Pandas plotted

[image]

So you can see the X and Y axis are scaled differently, but they are plotting the same dataset. And the pandas plotted has a point with < 2.5cm length, but all the lengths in my dataset are 3 or greater.

Comment: Try swap `ax.scatter(sepal_length, sepal_width)` to `ax.scatter(sepal_width, sepal_length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you think you reversed X,Y for Dataframe?

X = sepal_width
Y = sepal_length
**Numpy:**

```
ax.scatter(X, Y)
```

**Pandas:**

```
ax.scatter(sepal_length, sepal_width)
```

Comment: this worked, thank you! why is it switched for the pandas if it's plotting the same information?

Comment: It's not pandas. It's you who changed order of X & Y between numpy and pandas plotting.

Comment: HAHAH ok yes I see this now. Thanks, everyone!